# A Simple Toy ML problem that surprisingly fails to converge (or even "try"!)

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, gradient-descent, cosine-similarity, complex-numbers

This is a much simplified network from a real problem that, to me, has a surprising **INability** to learn a simple task via backprop, ie, it can't overfit or learn at all. This simple version has come at the cost of many gray hairs, and much simplification, and I truly ignored the option that something this *simple* would fail to learn, until finally I tested it, and, sure enough it fails.

*(Runnable version at bottom)*

This model is truly simple, and I think the code may explain itself better than me, but, I'll still give some exposition.

More explanation follows, but this simply is a FFNN(ish) tasked with turning input vectors into output vectors which, for this toy version are all drawn from `randn`, and all with the same dimension. My interest is in merely training this architecture so that it can accurately output the expected vectors, and I would be overjoyed if we could even overfit/memorize the training set. High accuracy input-output mapping is what we want to achieve (more than, IE, low loss).

Any ol' FFNN could learn this dataset, but I'm curious why **this architecture**, which can successfully perform the task, cannot be trained to perform the task via backprop.

So, to explain it more in depth:

1. A dataset is built out of random vectors in 2 classes, **True**, and **False**. 3 vectors are "baked in": `predicate_vec`, `true_vec`, and `false_vec`. The **True** class should map `predicate_vec --> true_vec`. The **False** class maps `<random_vectors>  --> false_vec`. The True pairing is repeated many times in the dataset. The False pairings have many different random vectors all mapping to the same `false_vec`.
2. In the model, `input` vectors are compared via cosine similarity with a model parameter called `predicate`, resulting in an output in `[-1, 1]`. If this model learns to high accuracy, this parameter `predicate` should approach high cosine similarity with the data's `predicate_vec`. This is a key thing I want to see.
3. The model also has parameters `true` and `false`, which are randomly initialized vectors. If the model were to train, these would also achieve high cosine similarity to the `true_vec` and `false_vec` in the data. Analytically, this would be the optimal solution.
4. if `cos_sim(input, predicate)` approaches `1.0` the network should output it's model parameter vector `true`. Otherwise, output parameter `false`. The `cos_sim` gives a smooth "predicate" output and is differentiable (as opposed to a threshold or `if` operator).
5. `loss` is defined as `1 - cosine_similarity(output, expected)`. I am less interested however in what the loss does, although it is minimized at the same point where the model achieves perfect accuracy.
6. I am mostly interested in *can it solve the problem*, IE, output vectors with high cosine similarity to the expected class, `true` or `false`, given its input.
7. I am also interested in probing the learned parameters `predicate`, `true`, and `false`, because we analytically **know** the ideal values in this toy problem. In a real use case, we won't, and these need to be learned by the model.

On that point, if you cheat and set the model's internal vectors to the expected values, the model performs with expectedly great accuracy and low loss. Also training doesn't degrade the performance (too much), so this is empirical proof that there is a stable fixed point in the loss landscape.

Here's the model:

```
class Sim(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, ):
        super(Sim, self).__init__()
        self.predicate = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(VEC_SIZE) * 1e-2)
        self.true = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(VEC_SIZE) * 1e-2)
        self.false = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(VEC_SIZE) * 1e-2)

    def forward(self, input):
        # input  : [batch_size, vec_size]
        # output : [batch_size, vec_size]
        batch_size = input.size(0)
        predicate = self.predicate.unsqueeze(0)
        matched = torch.cosine_similarity(predicate, input, dim=1)
        return (
            einsum('v, b -> bv', self.true, matched) +
            einsum('v, b -> bv', self.false, 1 - matched)
        )
```

The `self.predicate` should eventually approximate `predicate_vec`, and analogously for `self.true` and `self.false` converging to `true_vec` and `false_vec`. If it learns these expected values, mathematically it will achieve the lowest loss. Yet backprop can't get it there. Here's the data:

```
predicate_vec = torch.randn(VEC_SIZE)  # these are baked in
true_vec      = torch.randn(VEC_SIZE)
false_vec     = torch.randn(VEC_SIZE)

dataset = (
    # positives
    [(predicate_vec, true_vec) for _ in range(N_DATASET_POS)] +
    # negatives
    [(torch.randn(VEC_SIZE), false_vec) for _ in range(N_DATASET_POS)]
)

dataset_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset,
                                             batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                             shuffle=True)
```

**EDIT:** **Please**, to those saying the data is completely random, please look again! There are 2 classes, and a specific mapping. The specific vector `predicate_vec` must map to the specific `true_vec`. A randomly drawn vec is pseudo-orthogonal to `predicate_vec`, ie has a low cosine-similarity, and therefore any random vec is being asked here to map to `false_vec`. Below, I demonstrate a **cheat** where these values are hard-coded into the model, and it discriminates the classes perfectly. **They *are* discriminatable** and not random.

When this runs, the output looks something like this, where the loss does decrease some (which we don't particularly care about), but accuracy at the task doesn't improve at all. The poor accuracy is evidenced on the last line which shows `p` for similarity of `model.predicate` to `predicate_vec`, and likewise for `t ~ true`, and `f ~ false`. These numbers perform what appears to be a random walk. The loss decreases a bit, but even when run for many more epochs, no accuracy is ever achieved. Even after much experimentation with hyper params, SGD vs Adam, weight decay, LR, n_epochs, balance of true class vs false class in the dataset etc., the accuracy performs a random walk, even as the loss approaches some (high) shelf.

```
Epoch 260, Training Loss: 0.005365743
Epoch 270, Training Loss: 0.005237889
Epoch 280, Training Loss: 0.005211671
Epoch 290, Training Loss: 0.005140129
Epoch 300, Training Loss: 0.005135684
SIMILARITY OF LEARNED VECS: p=-0.352 t=-0.244 f=0.266
```

If I "cheat" and set the model's internal params to the known-good values, the loss starts out minimized, and the params are robust to the training procedure, IE, for arbitrarily many epochs, stochastic training doesn't perturb away from a high-accuracy model. Notice, the cos-sim of `predicate`, `true`, and `false` are all around `1.0` as expected. On epoch=0, the cheat gives us `p=1.0 t=1.0 f=1.0`, which means it's performing optimally, and can sufficiently map inputs to outputs appropriately for this task. SGD/Adam doesn't perturb away from this:

```
Epoch 570, Training Loss: 0.003478402
Epoch 580, Training Loss: 0.003488328
Epoch 590, Training Loss: 0.003480982
Epoch 600, Training Loss: 0.003456787
SIMILARITY OF LEARNED VECS: p=0.990 t=0.994 f=0.992
```

If I simplify the network by removing the `true` and `false`, change the dataset to `[(true_vec, 1.0), (false_vec, 0.0)]`, and have the network output a scalar `[-1, 1]` from the cosine similarity of `input` with `predicate`, it learns just fine. But the slightly more complex version, which uses that scalar to scale `model.true` and `model.false`, suddenly fails.

Also, taking a shot in the dark, I tried the original full version but with complex valued vectors throughout, and a hand-rolled `cosine_similarity`, and it worked.

So, that worked!? I have no idea why it worked, or why the previous versions didn't.

I'm really stumped! This problem seems like it should be **so simple** for backprop to settle in to. It doesn't have weird nonlinearities, no recurrence, not even any `Linear` layers, the entire chain is differentiable. The architecture is trivial. I've tried with SGD and AdamW, and myriad hyper params.

Any thoughts?

---

**Runnable version:**

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
from torch import einsum
import pdb
import torch
import numpy as np
import random
import string
from datasets import Dataset
torch.set_printoptions(precision=3)

SEED = 42
torch.manual_seed(SEED)
np.random.seed(SEED)
random.seed(SEED)

DEVICE = 'cuda'

##########
# Params

NUM_EPOCHS = 1000
BATCH_SIZE = 10
GRAD_CLIP = 10.0

LR = 1e-2
WD = 0

N_DATASET_POS = 100
N_DATASET_NEG = 100
VEC_SIZE = 128


##########
# Data

# We'll try and find these same vectors being learned within the network.
predicate_vec = torch.randn(VEC_SIZE)
true_vec = torch.randn(VEC_SIZE)
false_vec = torch.randn(VEC_SIZE)

dataset = (
    # positives
    [(predicate_vec, true_vec) for _ in range(N_DATASET_POS)] +
    # negatives
    [(torch.randn(VEC_SIZE), false_vec) for _ in range(N_DATASET_POS)]
)

dataset_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset,
                                             batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                             shuffle=True)

##########
# Model


class Sim(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, ):
        super(Sim, self).__init__()
        self.predicate = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(VEC_SIZE) * 1e-2)
        self.true = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(VEC_SIZE) * 1e-2)
        self.false = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(VEC_SIZE) * 1e-2)

    def forward(self, input):
        # input  : [batch_size, vec_size]
        # output : [batch_size, vec_size]
        batch_size = input.size(0)
        predicate = self.predicate.unsqueeze(0)
        matched = torch.cosine_similarity(predicate, input, dim=1)
        return (
            einsum('v, b -> bv', self.true, matched) +
            einsum('v, b -> bv', self.false, 1 - matched)
        )

def run_epoch(data_loader, model, optimizer):
    model.train()
    total_loss = 0
    all_predictions = []
    all_true_values = []

    for batch in data_loader:
        input_tensor, target_tensor = batch
        input_tensor = input_tensor.to(DEVICE)
        target_tensor = target_tensor.to(DEVICE)

        model.zero_grad()
        output = model(input_tensor)
        loss = (1 - torch.cosine_similarity(target_tensor, output.unsqueeze(1))).mean()

        loss.backward()
        torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), max_norm=GRAD_CLIP)
        optimizer.step()

        total_loss += loss.item() / target_tensor.size(1)

    return total_loss / len(data_loader)


##########
# Go

model = Sim()
model = model.to(DEVICE)

##########
# Cheat and set to expected value

# with torch.no_grad():
#     model.predicate[:] = predicate_vec
#     model.true[:] = true_vec
#     model.false[:] = false_vec

optimizer = torch.optim.AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=LR, weight_decay=WD)

def check(model):
    ''' Check how much internal vectors are aligning to known vectors. '''
    p = torch.cosine_similarity(model.predicate.to(DEVICE), predicate_vec.to(DEVICE), dim=0)
    t = torch.cosine_similarity(model.true.to(DEVICE),      true_vec.to(DEVICE), dim=0)
    f = torch.cosine_similarity(model.false.to(DEVICE),     false_vec.to(DEVICE), dim=0)
    print(f'SIMILARITY OF LEARNED VECS: p={p:>.3f} t={t:>.3f} f={f:>.3f}')

for epoch in range(NUM_EPOCHS):
    loss = run_epoch(dataset_loader, model, optimizer)
    if epoch % 10 == 0:
        print(f'Epoch {epoch}, Training Loss: {loss:>.9f}')

    if epoch % 100 == 0:
        check(model)
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, your data is completely random and there's no pattern whatsoever that would distinguish positive from negative cases, so there's nothing to learn…

Comment: @tim The data maps `[(predicate_vec, true_vec), (<random_vec>, false_vec)]`. `predicate_vec`, `true_vec`, and `false_vec` are all initially randomized, but baked in once at startup. `<random_vec>` is generated many different times. If you pre-set the internal paramaters `predicate`, `true`, and `false` to the originally baked `_vec`s, this demonstrates full accuracy in that the `model` will correctly map `predicate_vec` to `true_vec`, and anything else to `false_vec`. The logic in `forward` makes it clear I think, but, I'm happy to clarify if not!

Comment: @Tim since someone else upvoted that, I must have failed to clarify appropriately. The dataset is randomly generated yes, but in 2 classes, a positive class, and a negative class. The positive class is `N` repeated instances of the exact same mapping of `predicate_vec --> true_vec`. (Being repeated `N` times, it should be easy to overfit, one would think, which this fails to accomplish). The negative class maps `<N random vecs>  --> false_vec`. The dataset has 2 classes which are distinguishable by many even simple means. My problem though is why this specific architecture fails.

Comment: I understand that your network's loss is not decreasing. This could be because the network or loss function you've implemented has a mistake. However, we can't assess possible semantic errors because you have not described what your *intended operation* is (beyond getting the loss to go down). What is the *intended* model? The *intended* loss function? You'll probably need math typesetting to articulate this; here's how to do that: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Moreover, the "bad" model has loss 0.005 at epoch 300 while the "good" model has loss 0.003 at epoch 600 -- are you sure the problem isn't that the "good" model is trained for twice as long, which allows it to attain the better result?

Comment: @Sycorax I think this problem is so counterintuitive that the few people who have interacted with it have dismissed it, but I do know what I'm doing, and this is a strange problem. My purpose truly is to learn this dataset with this architecture. The "good" model achieves it's loss from epoch 0 because of the "cheat", so the point of showing later epochs is that SGD hasn't corrupted the model, IE, there is a fixed point in the loss landscape, but SGD isn't able to take it there. So my intended operation is  to yes, get the loss to go down, but also get the model params align with ideal values.

Comment: @Sycorax If I clarify this more would you mind reopening the question? It's truly a weird one, and this isn't some noob-type bug. I actually think it's an important problem.

Comment: Once you've [edit]ed your question, it will populate the reopen queue. I, or someone else, will vote to reopen the question once it's clarified. // I understand that your claim is that the network isn't learning, but the evidence you've provided is that the "bad" model model has a loss that is (slowly) decreasing at a certain epoch, compared to a "good" model that has a loss that is lower & slowly decreasing at a much later epoch. You must appreciate that an external observer will not find that the most compelling evidence of a problem!

Comment: Moreover, because the difference in the loss values between the "bad" model and the "cheat" model occurs in the third decimal, combined with the large discrepancies in the intended behaviors, makes me wonder if there is an implementation error somewhere in this code -- which is why I think you need to clarify the intended operations.

Comment: Well, your data is completely random. The only thing your model can do is to memorize the data and return it. There is nothing trivial about the problem, as there is no pattern that the model can learn. If it was discrete data, it could even be the case where by chance the same inputs would have different labels and there would be no way of distinguishing them. With continuous inputs you still can have similar inputs with different labels, what would make a hard problem. No surprises here at all.

Comment: @Tim I appreciate the review, but while the data is randomly generated, the mapping between the 2 classes is not random. There is a **true** class and a **false** class, that have specific mappings. For the true class, I want to map a specific `predicate` vector to a specific `true` vector, ie not a random vec. For the false class, I want to map any vec that's orthogonal to `predicate` to the `false` vec. In a high-dimensional space, any 2 random vecs are (pseudo) orthogonal with high prob. This dataset is most certainly not random. C-valued vecs actually solve this (but I don't know why)

Comment: @Sycorax I appreciate your feedback, and I am open to any other feedback as well if it needs more attention. If you're right and there is just some logical bug, I think this answer is still in scope for this forum. But I don't think there's a normal-type bug here, so, I have hopes that the problem and answer are far more interesting! :D

Comment: @Tim maybe I can prove it's not "random" by making it more tangible. It's like the cheerleading chant thing "When I say `predicate_vec`, you say `true_vec`", but also "If I say anything other than `predicate_vec`, then you say `false_vec`"!

Comment: @Josh.F The network is only computing a single inner product, so there's only a single vector (neglecting positive scale factors) with cosine similarity -1 to the predicate vector. Therefore, I don't think the network you've outlined here is actually learnable because "anything other than predicate vec" includes a great many vectors, not solely vectors with cosine similarity $-1$. I think you'd have more success with triplet networks, or something in that vein.

Comment: @Sycorax Because cos-sim compares angles, there are infinite vectors with similarity of -1 (or 1, which I want here), but you're right there's only one vector if all are normalized. And since this model is a piece of a larger problem, this *is* an accurate toy version of my actual use case where, I don't merely want to discriminate this dataset, but I want this architecture to train. Can we agree it's strange that it won't train, but we have evidence (via the **cheat**) that it is a sufficient architecture to properly inference with high accuracy? It's weird it won't train right?

Comment: @Sycorax so it *is* possible for this model to perform well. And, I noted briefly in there, if all vecs are complex-valued, it actually trains nearly instantaneously, like, within a few epochs - same architecture! Please tell me if I'm crazy, or if this actually is a counterintuitive problem :)

Comment: To avoid quibbling about the *positive rescaling* of the vectors, consider a model that's parameterized solely in terms of angles and I think my previous comment will become quite clear. To simplify further, consider the model where all components are two-dimensional: each vector is entirely defined by a single angle $\cos \theta, \sin\theta$, so we've further constrained all vectors are unit length.

Comment: @Sycorax I appreciate your attention on this problem, and I don't mean to quibble; I credited that your point was accurate given rescaling. I just don't understand how this leads to the correct mapping being unlearnable. I mention removing `model.true` and `model.false`, and then `model.predicate` is perfectly learnable, even given your point. I fail to see how the simple addition of the `true` and `false` vecs damages the ability to learn.

Comment: @Josh.F, to see why rescaling is important, compare the cosine similarity of $\left( 100, 100 \right)$ and $\left( 110, 90 \right)$ to the cosine similarity of $\left( 10, 10 \right)$ and $\left( 11, 9 \right)$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This question plagued me, and fuel on my flame was the fact that I had been told on this thread umpteen times by generous, albeit mistaken posters and upvoters, but I knew I was justified. This problem *is* learnable, and most certainly the generated data is *perfectly fine*.

I've been coming back to this problem on and off for weeks now, led astray by myriad red herrings (eg my suspicion that complex numbers helped was dead wrong), but the problem is a mere bug in the OP code:

```py
        output = model(input_tensor)
        loss = (1 - torch.cosine_similarity(target_tensor, output.unsqueeze(1))).mean()
```

Right there I do an `output.unsqueeze(1)`, but, `output` is shaped right as-is, and the `.unsqueeze(1)` causes a shape misalignment, which `cosine_similarity` is happy enough to broadcast through, and fail silently. So, the above code runs **fine** if you just delete `.unsqueeze(1)`. It learns to arbitrarily low loss, and high accuracy from a random initialization, and does so quickly.

I am grateful to my colleagues for their time and answers, and will continue to reflect on why this problem seemed to others impossible for any system to solve, by so many intelligent and generous people on this thread. Much love.

Answer (score 8):

## The problem isn't learnable because of how the data are generated.

Without loss of generality, we can consider vectors with 2 elements. Then the values of each vector are given by a single scalar, an angle $\theta$ and the vectors are always constrained to have unit length (which converts cosine similarity to a dot-product). These simplifications make it easier to examine what the model is doing.

The model parameters are given by the predicate vector is $p = [\cos \theta_p, \sin \theta_p]$, and likewise the vector true $t$ and false $f$.

A single input to the model is $x = [\cos \theta_x, \sin \theta_x]$, and the target is $y = [\cos \theta_y, \sin \theta_y]$.

First, we compute the cosine similarity of $p$ and $x$:
$$\begin{align}
p^T x 
&= \cos \theta_p \cos \theta_x + \sin \theta_p \sin \theta_x \\
&= \cos(\theta_p - \theta_x) \\
&= \cos \Delta \\
\end{align}$$
So $p$ and $x$ are most similar when the angle between them is 0.

Denote $m$ the result of the sums of the two Einstein summation notation expressions used in the code. We know $p^T x$ is a scalar, so we're just summing scalar multiples of the two vectors.

$$\begin{align}
m &= \begin{bmatrix}
\cos \theta_t \cos \Delta + \cos \theta_f (1 - \cos \Delta) \\
\sin \theta_t \cos \Delta + \sin \theta_f (1 - \cos \Delta)
\end{bmatrix} \\
\end{align}$$

The general expression for $m$ is handy to have. We'll consider the two special cases where $\cos \Delta = 0$ and $\cos \Delta = 1$ because they simplify things. These are the two cases that OP has expressed as the ultimate objective: map the input to $t$ when the input has a small angle to $p$; otherwise, map it to $f$.

$$\begin{align}
m_{\cos \Delta = 1} &= \begin{bmatrix}
\cos \theta_t\\
\sin \theta_t
\end{bmatrix} \\
m_{\cos \Delta = 0} &= \begin{bmatrix}
\cos \theta_f \\
\sin \theta_f
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}$$

The loss is computed as $1 - m^T y$ where $y$ is the target. This loss is maximized at 2 and minimized at 0.

In your example, all of the true cases have a single input vector and a single output vector. However, all of the inputs for the false cases are random, and all of the targets have the same vector. This is where the problem arises.

When the input is a false case, then the desired result is that $p^T x = \cos \Delta = 0$. This only arises when $p$ and $x$ are orthogonal. In this case, there are only 2 such vectors. But the randomized way that the inputs to the false case are generated means that these inputs are unlikely to correspond to vectors orthogonal to $p$.

So we have an impossible circumstance: we can't fix $p$ at a value that will minimize the loss on any 2 distinct false examples $x$ — unless those vectors are orthogonal to $p$. In the code, the false examples are generated completely at random, so the normalized vectors are scattered all over the surface of the unit sphere. In a large enough sample, some of these samples will even be close to the $x$ for the true examples.

Moreover, if we choose a $p$ that minimizes the loss on the true examples, then that will only minimize the loss on the false examples for the cases where the inputs to the false examples are orthogonal to it. This is unlikely to occur for any of your false examples, and even if one false example has this occur, it will be "averaged away" by all of the false examples for which it does not occur.

You've stated in comments that if we rescale the vectors, then there are infinitely many orthogonal vectors. This is of no consequence for the learnability of the problem. Your network and loss function are entirely framed in terms of cosine similarity, so all that matters is the angle between the vectors.

---

However, there are lots of kinds of neural networks designed to map inputs that belong to the same class to the same location in some latent space; one example is [triplet-loss](/questions/tagged/triplet-loss). They still require the data to have some learnable signal, though.

Comment: I really appreciate your thoughtful answer, and it sounds like you understand my plight nearly perfectly. I've reread it several times, and I *think* there are a couple flaws, possibly immaterial, possibly material. "we can't fix p at a value that mins loss": I demonstrate that we can above - exactly `predicate_vec`. And to your point of reducing to a 2d angle, and  that random vecs are varying degrees of  parallel to `p` - random vecs are *very* likely orthogonal https://mathoverflow.net/questions/248466/why-are-two-random-vectors-in-mathbb-rn-approximately-orthogonal-for-large

Comment: I'll keep rereading, and experimenting to see if I can further explain my view, or understand how yours was right and I was just dense :)

Comment: Oh, and about orthogonal vecs, I did understand your point that rescaling is meaningless to cos-sim. In a high-dimensional space, there are still infinite *unit* vecs that are orthogonal to a given vec. So not in 2D, but even in 3D there are infinite orthogonal vecs. This may be part of the reason why my network can (if hand set) discriminate all non-predicates, and map them to `false_vec`.

Comment: I'm still reading through this, and, another point stands out. "They still require the data to have some learnable signal". To be clear, are you saying this synthetic dataset does not have a learnable signal? Despite the several upvotes on @Tim's comment suggesting my dataset is random, I still hold that it is not random, and add further evidence that the network can be set with the `predicate`, `true`, and `false` vectors which perfectly *optimize* this problem's performance / *minimize* its loss. Beyond this toy prob, I want to *learn* these params, so different architectures wont suffice :(

Comment: @Josh.F As Sycorax explained, this problem is ill-defined and not learnable, or in some very favorable scenarios and interpretations of it, very hard and a neural network would not be well-suited here. If you insist that you want to memorize the training data, then you don't need a neural network here, just create a set consisting of the training data, and for values in the set return the "positive" label, and "negative" otherwise. However, as I noted in the comments, even this does not necessarily would give you good performance if there are overlaps.

Comment: @Tim forgive me to keep pressing, but it is not ill defined and it is learnable. 2 points of evidence. 1. i can set by hand the model params to achieve perfect loss+accuracy. 2. if I keep everything the same but use Complex valued vecs everywhere (data, params) instead of Real valued, it also *learns* from a random initialization, via backprop, though I dont know why. When you say it is "ill-defined and not learnable", are you accounting for these 2 facts I have previously mentioned? because if you are, then you are right and I have some soul searching to do :)